# How to add default classname on the images i upload with CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, html, web, ckeditor

Like the topic says: How to add default classname on the images i upload with CKEditor?
Cant relly find any information regarding this

Comment: I would post-process them in. How do you save your content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( ev )
{
 var editor = ev.editor;
  var dataProcessor = editor.dataProcessor,
             htmlFilter = dataProcessor && dataProcessor.htmlFilter;
             htmlFilter.addRules(
             {
                 elements:
                 {
                     $: function (element) {
                          if (element.name == 'img') {
                             if (!element.attributes['class']){
                                  element.attributes['class'] = "helloworld";
                             }
                         }
                         return element;
                     }
                 }
             });
 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z6y8q6rm/2/