# Altering CKEditor HTML content after instanceReady and paste

Tags: ckeditor

I need to add `contenteditable="false"` on all CKEditor content elements having CSS `class="readonly"` and `contenteditable="true"` to elements having CSS `class="writable"`. Preferably on paste and instance ready.

I know of `config.on.instanceReady` and `config.on.paste` but what should I write into the function just eludes me ;)

Btw. I'm not using inline editor.

editor.document is listed as read only property in the documentation so I cannot use that.

Final solution thanks to [Oleq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1485219/oleq) for showing me to the right path. applyToAll is required if writables are within readonly.

```
 // Add custom rule to dataFilter (when data comes *into* editor).
 on{pluginsLoaded: function (evt){
 this.dataProcessor.dataFilter.addRules( {
     elements: {
         $: function ( element ) {
             if (element.hasClass('readonly'))
             {
                 element.attributes.contenteditable = 'false';
             }

             if (element.hasClass('writable'))
             {
                 element.attributes.contenteditable = 'true';
             }
         }
     }
  },{applyToAll: true});


  this.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules( {
      elements: {
          $: function ( element ) {
              if(element.hasClass('readonly') || element.hasClass('writable'))
              {
                  delete element.attributes.contenteditable;
              }
          }
      }
  },{applyToAll: true});

  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use CKEditor's [`dataProcessor.dataFilter`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.htmlDataProcessor-property-dataFilter). This is the standard mechanism used by the editor to filter input ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oleq/47hd0qLq/)). It handles data set with [`editor.setData`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-setData), data pasted by the user and, of course, initial HTML from textarea or any element to which CKEditor is attached.

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'my-editor', {
    // See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15659962/1485219
    extraAllowedContent: 'span(readonly)',

    // Just to make the interface clear.
    toolbarGroups: [
        {"name":"document","groups":["mode"]},
        {"name":"basicstyles","groups":["basicstyles"]}
    ],
    on: {
        // When all plugins were loaded but editor data is not yet processed.
        pluginsLoaded: function( evt ) {
            // Add custom rule to dataFilter (when data comes *into* editor).
            this.dataProcessor.dataFilter.addRules( {
                elements: {
                    // Check all elements. Rules can be specific, i.e. for img or h2.
                    $: function( element ) {
                        if ( element.hasClass( 'readonly' ) ) {
                            element.attributes.contenteditable = "false";
                        }
                    }
                }
            } );
        }
    }
} );
```

---

EDIT: I created you a widget ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oleq/Lrfntkq9/)) because I feel this is what you really wanted to do:

```
// This plugin brings a widget into editor.
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'myFirstWidget', {
    // Widget plugin must be loaded (must be present in the build of CKEditor).
    requires: 'widget',

    init: function( editor ) {
        editor.widgets.add( 'myFirstWidget', {        
            button: 'My First Widget Button',

            // http://stackoverflow.com/a/15659962/1485219
            allowedContent: 'span(readonly)',                            
            requiredContent: 'span(readonly)',

            // Make all <span class="readonly"> a non-editable widget. 
            upcast: function( element ) {
                return element.name == 'span' && element.hasClass( 'readonly' );
            }
        } );        
    }
} );

CKEDITOR.replace( 'my-editor', {
    // Use the plugin.
    extraPlugins: 'myFirstWidget',

    // Just to make the interface clear.
    toolbar: [ [ 'Source', '-', 'MyFirstWidget' ] ]
} );
```

[Learn more about widgets and awesomeness they bring](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/widget_sdk_intro).

Comment: Thanks it worked what about removing contenteditable attributes on getData()?

Comment: Use `dataProcessor.htmlFilter` the same way as `dataProcessor.dataFilter`. Some [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26587645/how-to-add-default-classname-on-the-images-i-upload-with-ckeditor/26740247#26740247).

Comment: thanks. I usually fiddle with CKEditor once or twice a year and I had totally forgot these even exist.

Comment: You should check [CKEditor Widgets](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/widget_sdk_intro) ([also in SDK](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/simplebox.html)). I feel that this is what you wanted to do but somehow you missed it.

Comment: Actually Widgets were not what I was after here. I have email template editor on another page. There you can edit every element and mark HTML parts as writable or readonly with mentioned CSS classes.

On actual email editor only writable parts of the chosen template are editable based on mentioned classes.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in JavaScript:

```
var readOnlyEls = document.querySelectorAll('.readonly');
for (var i=0; i < readOnlyEls.length; i++) {
    readOnlyEls[i].setAttribute("contenteditable", false);
}

var writableEls = document.querySelectorAll('.writable');
for (var i=0; i < writableEls .length; i++) {
    writableEls[i].setAttribute("contenteditable", true);
}
```

Or if you are using jQuery:

```
$(".readonly").attr("contenteditable", false);
$(".writable").attr("contenteditable", true);
```

Comment: But how to get editing area's document element? I'm not using inline editor.